# If column matches another file, print every line with match (awk/grep)

Tags: awk, grep

I’m taking two input files, one with certain ID numbers, and another with a large list of ID numbers and additional columns. The latter file contains multiple lines for each ID number and I need to extract all lines that match an ID from the first file. Those lines then must be printed in a new file.

Edit 1: Replaced sample files with excerpts from actual

Edit 2: Removed extra spaces that were in excerpt, but not actual file. Files likely need to be sanitized in some way, but how is unclear.

file1:

```
AT1G56430
AT3G55190
AT3G22880
```

file2:

```
AT1G01010|GO:0043090|RCA
AT1G56430|GO:0010233|IGI 
AT1G56430|GO:0009555|IGI 
AT1G56430|GO:0030418|IGI
```

expected output

```
AT1G56430|GO:0010233|IGI 
AT1G56430|GO:0009555|IGI 
AT1G56430|GO:0030418|IGI
```

[[image: file1ss][[image: file2ss]

I have tried:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0' file1 file2 > output.txt
```

and:

```
grep -Ff file2 file1 > output.txt
```

I’m aware that there are many somewhat similar questions posted in these forums and others. However, these don’t mention how the output is handled… nor do they mention duplicates. I’ve tried solutions from 4 of them, have been messing with this for many hours and keep getting the same problem: a blank output file.

I’m new to awk and I greatly appreciate the help. Sorry if this is a simple problem with syntax etc; please let me know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you try my awk command ?

Comment: Yes I did; not clear what's preventing it from working.

Comment: What does `grep AT1G56430 file2` output? How about `file file1 file2`? (Could there be an issue with Windows line-endings?)

Comment: post the output of od -c < file1

Comment: The files were prepared in Microsoft Excel 2008 for Mac. `grep AT1G56430 file2`
appears to output the entire file, surprisingly.

`file file1 file2` gives


`file1: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
file2: ASCII text, with CR line terminators`...

`od -c <file1` gives...
`0000000   A   T   1   G   5   6   4   3   0  \r   A   T   3   G   5   5
0000020   1   9   0  \r   A   T   3   G   2   2   8   8   0  \r   A   T` and many more lines

Comment: it clearly says.. you have the windows line endings ( \r ). you need to remove the \r before you grep or running the awk command. refer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix) and use tr or dos2unix command

Comment: No, those are Mac line endings; you need to sanitize the files with `tr '\r' '\n'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your AWK script is nearly there:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] > 0' file1 file2 > output.txt
```

works, after changing the line-endings from Mac to Unix:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < file1 > file1.new
mv file1.new file1
tr '\r' '\n' < file2 > file2.new
mv file2.new file2
```

`$1` is the first field in AWK.

Instead of `c[$1] > 0`, you can write `c[$1]`. The `> 0` isn't needed: any non-zero value works, so we might as well use the contents of `c` directly:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1]' file1 file2 > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

give a try this awk command.

```
bash-4.1$ cat file1
1
3

bash-4.1$ cat file2
1|A|B
1|C|D
2|E|F
3|G|H

bash-4.1$ awk -F\| 'NR==FNR{F1[$0];next}$1 in F1{print}' file1 file2
1|A|B
1|C|D
3|G|H
```

Comment: I entered the command exactly as follows and am getting the same issue. `cat file1 | cat file2 | awk -F\| 'NR==FNR{F1[$0];next}$1 in F1{print}' file1 file2 > output7.txt` The purpose of concatenation isn't clear to me, nor is the reason for using `cat file1 | cat file2` instead of `cat file1 file2`. I would appreciate clarification and further advice. 

Thanks.

Comment: cat file1 and cat file2 is to show the contents of my file. for the solution, just run the awk command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `join` already?

```
$ tail -n +1 -- file1 file2
==> file1 <==
AT1G56430
AT3G55190
AT3G22880

==> file2 <==
AT1G01010|GO:0043090|RCA
AT1G56430|GO:0010233|IGI 
AT1G56430|GO:0009555|IGI 
AT1G56430|GO:0030418|IGI

$ join -t'|' file1 file2
AT1G56430|GO:0010233|IGI 
AT1G56430|GO:0009555|IGI 
AT1G56430|GO:0030418|IGI
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem with this. Perhaps it's some problem with my files, as I mentioned as a reply to another answer here, but we're having a hard time figuring out what that problem is.